# Converting boolean expressions to polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2$: Does it yield a simple way to simplify boolean expressions?

Tags: polynomials, boolean-algebra

I made a silly experiment: I tried to find polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which match the boolean operations. I have found:

$$a\wedge b \mapsto ab \;\; (mod\; 2) \quad \quad a\vee b \mapsto a+ab+b \;\; (mod\; 2)\quad \quad ¬a \mapsto a+1 \;\; (mod\; 2) \tag{1}$$

I noticed that coefficients and powers are superfluous: If a coefficient is odd, we can replace it by $1$, if even we can erase the monomial. I remember when learning about logic that we can represent any boolean function with a certain procedure, but this procedure don't always give the shortest expression for a given boolean function: There are ways to simplify it such as Veitch-Karnaugh maps, for example: From the truth-table for the multiplexer, we arrive at the following expression:

$$(x\wedge ¬y \wedge ¬ z)\vee (x\wedge y \wedge ¬ z)\vee (¬x\wedge y \wedge  z)\vee (x\wedge y \wedge  z) \tag{2}$$

But there is the much simpler expression:

$$( x \wedge ¬z) \vee (y \wedge z) \tag{3}$$

I thought that perhaps, converting the boolean expressions such as $(2)$ to the polynomials I found in $(1)$ and knowing that coefficients and exponents are superfluous, it could yield a natural way to simplify such expressions. I converted $(2)$ using $(1)$ and simplified, it gave me:

$$xz+x+yz$$

From which I can simplify to:

$$x(z+1)+yz$$

Now it seems that this expression is very similar to $(3)$ if we interpret $z+1$ as $¬z$. I'm not sure if this is a general process that works every time or if I was just lucky. Supposing it works, I found this process to be very easy to simplify boolean expressions. I have no idea on how to prove this. Could you help me?

Comment: It's basically just a tool to help your brain use the intuition it has gained from years of doing algebra on logic statements, which is why you find it easier to do that way. I see nothing wrong with it, though, as long as you're careful when translating between the two (use parentheses liberally).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's not always going to be simplifying, for instance
$$a\vee b\vee c\vee d \quad=\quad a+b+c+d+ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd+abc+abd+bcd+acd+abcd$$

Comment: Though, $a \vee b \vee c \vee d =(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)+1$ is not so bad.

Comment: @user376343 Good point! How about something like $a\vee (b\wedge (c\vee (d\wedge e)))$